# c# method overloading and optional parameters

Tags: c#, overloading, option-type

Say I have these 2 functions:

```
    public void Test(int Param1)
    {
        //do something
    }

    public void Test(int Param1, int Param2 = 1)
    {
        //do something
    }
```

If I execute this:
     Test(2)

How does the compiler know which function to execute? It could be any of them: the first one which only accepts 1 parameter or the second one which accepts 1 or 2 parameters.

In fact I'm surprised that the above code even compiles.

Comment: I encourage you to read section 7.5.3.2 "Better Function Member" of the C# 4 specification.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx "If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters."